# Merging data using smartbind

Tags: r

I have 2 data tables, one with:

```
    X1          X2          X3          X4
1   ClaimIDs    ClaimIDs    ClaimIDs    ClaimIDs
2   427         419         399         399
```

and another with

```
    row.names   X1  X2  X3  X4
1   3852        0   0   0   20
2   3853        0   0   0   8
3   3854        0   0   0   10
```

I would like to make it so that it looks like this:

```
    row.names   X1          X2          X3          X4
1   NA          ClaimIDs    ClaimIDs    ClaimIDs    ClaimIDs
2   NA          427         419         399         399 
3   3852        0           0           0           20
4   3853        0           0           0           8
5   3854        0           0           0           10
```

I have tried everything from r and c bind to smartbind, even to using a listing variable.  It always either outputs with too many columns filled with NAs or does not add in the 3852, 3853, 3854 into the right spots.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  I can provide any code that is needed to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `merge`

```
 merge(df1, df2, by=names(df1), all=TRUE)
 #           X1       X2       X3       X4 row.names
 #1        0        0        0       10      3854
 #2        0        0        0       20      3852
 #3        0        0        0        8      3853
 #4      427      419      399      399        NA
 #5 ClaimIDs ClaimIDs ClaimIDs ClaimIDs        NA
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)
 rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill=TRUE)
 #         X1       X2       X3       X4 row.names
 #1: ClaimIDs ClaimIDs ClaimIDs ClaimIDs        NA
 #2:      427      419      399      399        NA
 #3:        0        0        0       20      3852
 #4:        0        0        0        8      3853
 #5:        0        0        0       10      3854
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c("ClaimIDs", "427"), X2 = c("ClaimIDs", 
 "419"), X3 = c("ClaimIDs", "399"), X4 = c("ClaimIDs", "399")),
.Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))

 df2 <- structure(list(row.names = 3852:3854, X1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
 X2 = c(0L, 
 0L, 0L), X3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), X4 = c(20L, 8L, 10L)),
.Names = c("row.names", 
"X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: that doesnt seem to work sorry.  I am very new to R and My position wants me to learn as I go.  I tried that and i got the error: 

1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: Based on the data you showed, I am getting the expected output as you showed.

Comment: @ChristopherYee  I think you have `factor` columns.  Please change it to character columns before `merge`.  i.e. `df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)`

Comment: perfect thanks! the second one worked.  I just gotta try to get the row.names into the front.

Comment: @ChristopherYee  No problem, it happens, Thanks for the reply